# Taking the months out of a string that is within a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have a vector pair of dates and payments that looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double>> payments = { {"8/18", 0.0}, {"7/18", 771.98}, {"6/18", 0.0}, {"5/18", 771.98},
                                                    {"4/18", 771.98}, {"3/18", 771.98}, {"2/18", 0.0}, {"1/18", 3859.90},
                                                    {"12/17", 771.98}, {"11/17", 0.0}, {"10/17", 1543.96}, {"9/17", 771.98} };
```

I want to take the months out of each first element and put it into a vector of ints i.e.

```
 payment_months = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,12,11,10,9]
```

I tried doing this:

```
std::vector<int> paymentMonths;
for (auto it : payments)
{
    paymentMonths.push_back(it.first[0] - '0');
}
```

This gives me

```
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 1 1 9
```

So the problem is when I get to the the months of December, November, and October. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem please. Post a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem you're stuck with as required here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Edited with an example

Comment: Why are you storing dates as a string rather than a Date/Time class that can deal with all the nitty-gritty of time?

Comment: Break the problem down.  The issue is not with vector, as you already are getting the string correctly. The issue is one of taking a string delimited by a slash and getting the first token.

Comment: Why not using a map to get a month-int from a month-string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some of your months have more than one digit representing them what you need to do is get the sub string of the date string that just has the month part, and then you can convert that to a integer using `stoi`.  That would make you loo look like

```
std::vector<int> paymentMonths;
for (auto it : payments)
{
    paymentMonths.push_back(std::stoi(it.first.substr(0, it.first.find("/"))));
}
```

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Your welcome.  Do note that I did not include error checking in this.  If your strings might not be in the form of `"xx/yy"` then this could cause an issue.